# Using async pipe with angular-modal-gallery

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use `angular-modal-gallery` plugin to display a number of images from urls returned from a service as json.

the modal gallery works fine if I hard code per the demos. However, it stops working when I try to hook in my service.

In my component.html I have;

```
<ks-modal-gallery [id]="1" [modalImages]="myModalImages | async"></ks-modal-gallery>
```

then in the component.ts;

```
myModalImages: Image[];
myModalImagesSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService, private imageService: ImageService) {

    this.myModalImagesSubscription = this.imageService.getModalImages().subscribe((result: Image[]) => {
        this.myModalImages = result;
    });
}
```

Where the `getModalImages()` is;

```
    getModalImages(): Observable<Image[]> {

    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + "/image/portfolio/modal/", this.buildRequestOptions())
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now the api is being hit and the Json with the results returned. However, when I run the SPA I get the following error;

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at ModalGalleryComponent.initImages

I have also tried the amending the following to return the `Observable` object;

```
myModalImages: Observable<Image[]>;


constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService, private imageService: ImageService) {

    this.myModalImages = this.imageService.getModalImages();
}
```

Which suggests its trying to initialize prior to getting the images?

Can anyone please direct me and tell me what I a doing wrong here?

Finally I have tried removing the `async` pipe and initializing the array as follows;

```
myModalImages: Image[] = [];

myModalImagesSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService, private imageService: ImageService) {

    this.myModalImagesSubscription = this.imageService.getModalImages().subscribe((result: Image[]) => {
        this.myModalImages = result;
    });
}
```

with the following in the html;

```
<ks-modal-gallery [id]="1" [modalImages]="myModalImages"></ks-modal-gallery>
```

I then get the following error;

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at CatchSubscriber.BaseService.handleError [as selector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't subscribe to the service. `async` pipe will do that for you. Assign the returned observable to `myModalImages` property.

```
constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService, private imageService: ImageService) {

    this.myModalImages= this.imageService.getModalImages() ;
}
```

Comment: sorry I have tried this too and it didnt work (same error) I'll update the question again

Comment: then just use `[modalImages]="myModalImages"`

Comment: Thanks for that, I have updated my question with the results (I initialized the array which removed that error) but it brought an new issue up?

Comment: apologies I got that due to a typo, I'll update the question with the results but short of it is by initializing the array i.e. `Image[] = [];` the callback 'this.myModalImages = result;` doesnt seem to overwrite the array, as its coming back as empty

Comment: seems like a seperate issue, so I raised a seperate question, thanks Sachila.